# Add symbol on top of ggplot2 boxplots to indicate value of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Working with the following subset of a much larger dataset,

```
ex <- structure(list(transect_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), number_f = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), years_f = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), b = c(5.036625862, 6.468666553, 8.028989792, 4.168409348, 
5.790089607, 10.67796993, 9.371051788, 10.54364777, 6.904324532, 
7.203606129, 9.1611166)), .Names = c("transect_id", "number_f", 
"years_f", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L))
```

I've plotted the distributions of "b" for each of the groups indicated by "transect_id" and have colored them by "number_f", which I do here:

```
ggplot(aes(x=reorder(transect_id, b, FUN=median), y=b), data=ex) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=as.factor(number_f))) + xlab('Transect ID')
```

[image]

**What I need to do for each of the "transect_id" groups is stack symbols - asterisks or some other symbol - on top of each boxplot to provide an indication of the value of "years_f" that corresponds to each "transect_id". In the data subset below, "years_f" amounts to 1 and 6 for transect_ids 1 and 15, respectively. I'd like to see something like this, which I manually mocked up.**

[image]

Also keep in mind that the dataset I'm working with is very large so I'll need to use some loop or some other way of doing this automatically. Please note that I absolutely welcome other ideas for better ways of indicating the value of "years_f" that might not overburden the figure as much as having all of these stacked symbols that will particularly be an issue for larger values of "years_f".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
annotate('text', x = c(1, 2), y = 3, label =  paste0('Year_F =', unique(ex$years_f)))
```

to the end of your plot like so:

```
ggplot(aes(x=reorder(transect_id, b, FUN=median), y=b), data=ex) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=as.factor(number_f))) + xlab('Transect ID')+ 
    annotate('text', x = c(1, 2), y = 3, label =  paste0('Year_F =', unique(ex$years_f)))
```

[image]

To use it on a bigger dataset you would have to edit the `x` and `y` argument, but this might be a decent alternative. A possibility for the `y` coordinate could be something like `0.9 * min(ex$b)`.

**edit** In response to your comment:

You could first count how many levels there are of `transect_id` to specify `x`

```
len.levels <- length(levels(as.factor(ex$transect_id)))
```

then, you could create a summary table of the uniqe `years_f` variable by `transect_id`:

```
sum.table <- aggregate(years_f~reorder(ex$transect_id, ex$b, median),
                       data = ex, FUN = unique)

  reorder(ex$transect_id, ex$b, median) years_f
1                                     1       1
2                                    15       6
```

and then plot as follows:

```
ggplot(aes(x=reorder(transect_id, b, FUN=median), y=b), data=ex) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=as.factor(number_f))) + xlab('Transect ID')+ 
  annotate('text', x = 1:len.levels, y = .9 * min(ex$b), 
           label =  paste0('Year_F =', sum.table[,2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not quite sure how to adapt your code to the larger dataset because the years_f values repeat themselves. So, there could be 12 unique values of years_of for the 50 transects. Also, how could I modify the x argument so that I don't need to manually specify?

Comment: Check my edit, is it okay? Also, are you planning on plotting 50 boxplots?

Comment: That works well--thank you for making those edits. Yes, I'm plotting 50 boxplots. I'm still going to try and figure out how to realize my original vision of stacked asterisks, but this is an excellent alternative. Thank you!